# Using PDE and Fourier Transform to solve an equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform

I'm solving this equation: $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}= k \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}$, with the following conditions:

1. $ t\geq0$
2. $-\infty<x<\infty$
3. $ u(x,0) = f(x)$
4. $ \mathscr{F} \{u(x,t)\} =U(s,t)$

Firts I need to find $U(s,t)$, then I have to find an general expression of $u(x,t)$ in terms of  $f(x)$ using the convolution theorem, and then make $f(x)=1$ to find $u(x,t)$

The way I am solving the problem is:

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}= k\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}$, with $u(x,t)=\mathscr{T}(t)\mathscr{X}(x)$

$\frac{\partial \mathscr{T}(t)\mathscr{X}(x)}{\partial t}= k\frac{\partial^2 \mathscr{T}(t)\mathscr{X}(x)}{\partial x^2}$

$\mathscr{X}\frac{\partial \mathscr{T}}{\partial t}= k\mathscr{T}\frac{\operatorname{d}^2 \mathscr{X}}{\operatorname{d} x^2}$ , now divided by $\frac{1}{u(x,t)}$

$\frac{1}{\mathscr{T}}\frac{\partial \mathscr{T}(t)}{\partial t} - \frac{k}{\mathscr{X}}\frac{\operatorname{d}^2 \mathscr{X}}{\operatorname{d} x^2}=0$ , Since the only way for these equations to be zero is that they are both equivalent to a constant.

$\frac{1}{\mathscr{T}}\frac{\partial \mathscr{T}(t)}{\partial t} =\frac{k}{\mathscr{X}}\frac{\operatorname{d}^2 \mathscr{X}}{\operatorname{d} x^2}= -m^2$, therefore we obtain two equations:

$\frac{\partial \mathscr{T}}{\partial t}+\mathscr{T}m^2=0$ and $\frac{\operatorname{d}^2 \mathscr{X}}{\operatorname{d} t^2}+\frac{\mathscr{X}m^2}{k}=0$, therefore the solutions are:

$\mathscr{T}(t)=Ae^{-mt}$ and $\mathscr{X}(x)=B\cos(\frac{m}{\sqrt{k}})+C\sin(\frac{m}{\sqrt{k}})$

${u(x,t)}= Ae^{-mt}[B\cos(\frac{m}{\sqrt{k}})+C\sin(\frac{m}{\sqrt{k}})]$, Now to find out $u(s,t)$, do the following:

$U(s,t)= \mathscr{F} \{u(x,t)\} $

$U(s,t)= \mathscr{F} \{Ae^{-mt}[B\cos(\frac{m}{\sqrt{k}})+C\sin(\frac{m}{\sqrt{k}})]\}$

$U(s,t)= ABe^{-mt}\mathscr{F}\{\cos(\frac{m}{\sqrt{k}})\} + ACe^{-mt}\mathscr{F}\{\sin(\frac{m}{\sqrt{k}})\} $

$U(s,t)=ABe^{-mt}[\pi\delta(s+\frac{m}{\sqrt{k}})+\pi\delta(s-\frac{m}{\sqrt{k}})]+ACe^{-mt}[i\pi\delta(s-\frac{m}{\sqrt{k}})-\pi\delta(s+\frac{m}{\sqrt{k}})]$

Now I don't have idea how to find $u(x,t)$ in terms of $f(x)$ using the convolution theorem.

Comment: I'm really not sure what you have done, though it seems you have used separation of variables which is not how you can solve this problem. Why don't you just use the Fourier transform on the PDE directly \begin{align} u_{t} &= ku_{xx} \\ \implies U_{t} &= - k s^{2} U \\ \implies U(s,t) &= F(s) e^{-k s^{2} t} \qquad (\text{where } F(s) = \mathcal{F}\{f(x)\}) \\ \implies u(x,t) &= \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{\mathbb{R}} F(s) e^{-k s^{2} t} e^{isx} ds \end{align} where the FT convention has been used to (hopefully?) match the transform you are using.

Comment: I was using separation of variables, and you are rigth I used Fourier Transfrom that way I solved the problem, thanks for the help.